# Unable to SSH into my EC2 instance from a different computer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, bitnami

A little backstory, I have an AWS instance made with Bitnami that I set up on my Windows Machine back home. I am currently out of the country and have no way to access that machine at the moment. One month later, I visit the website getting a 500 error and (only my Macbook on me). I've tried to SSH into it from my Macbook and no luck. I get the error:

*Username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.*

I've also tried another way to SSH into my aws but then I just get

*Permission denied (publickey).*

I do have the public/private keys I made with me so I am not sure if I had to set up some additional permissions to SSH from a different computer. On top of that, I got an email stating that someone attempted to access remote hosts on the internet without authorization. If I visit my Public IP address of my instance, it goes straight to a spam page.

At this point, I am not sure if I am just missing something in my steps or have missed a step. If someone can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Is there some way to get my instance back up and running? If not, is there some way I can back up the wordpress files on that instance that's down and use it to create another one on my Macbook currently? Please let me know.

Comment: Did you use the -i argument to specify the public key?

Comment: There's a few things you can try: "ssh -vvv -i <your-key-file>"  The -vvv will add verbose logging so you can check what's happening in the request and the -i will ensure you're submitting your public key file in the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the private key that your AWS instance has been installed with, place the key in `~/.ssh` .

Then, run the following command to set the permissions of the key to read and write only to your user (it's a mandatory step):

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/keyname
```

Then, run the following command to connect to your instance:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyname user@instance_ip
```

And it should connect successfully.

If you're not sure which user to connect to and you have access to AWS EC2 Console, then look for that server, right-click it and choose "Connect" and it will usually show the correct user to use when connecting to it by SSH.